# Open URL when clicking on a slide image using ColorBox jQuery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Hi I'm using the jQuery ColorBox from Jack Moore: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

I can't seem to figure out how to open a new URL when the user clicks on a slide image. For example, if the user clicks on my first slide photo, visit URL1, then if they click on the second slide photo, URL2, etc.

I tried searching the FAQ and Stack Overflow but didn't find solutions, thank you.